# UIWebView text improperly rendered at first after changing font family

Tags: javascript, objective-c, ios, uiwebview

I'm trying to change font of the text shown in a UIWebView using javascript. I'm doing this by  calling a javascript function which adds a css rule to span and paragraph elements.

Problem is that when I do this for the first time after application is opened, at first webview is rendered with the new font, but after near 2-3 seconds, location of words are slided a little bit, such like if I narrowed the line spacing of the text.

After first load, all other font change requests work properly, spacing and positions not change after text is visible.

What could be the reason behind this strange behavior? What can i do to solve this?

I tried adding css rule directly into html code, but it does not change the result.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tested the script with Safari ?

Comment: yes i've tried with mobile safari, but there is no such a problem for that.

i'm also using a css3 feature, dynamic column splitting using  "webkit-column-gap" and "webkit-column-width" attributes. maybe using both them results in this problem. but it should not behave like that.

Comment: If it behaves well in Safari, i'd address it as a bug report to Apple. A dummy workaround might be to load a short formatted text into 1x1px or maybe even invisible web view before loading the UI webViews.

Answer (score 0):

Try apply this css `padding-left: 5px; margin-left: -5px;` on spans. Padding is the space to correct rendering text and margin is to get element back to original position.